# Does chrome load videos in a different way than firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, html5-video

When trying to load videos onto a Three.js texture, I noticed that the Chrome is loading a video in ~2Mb chunks and playing the video once the chunk loads:

## CHROME:[image: chrome video loading]

I am comparing this with firefox where a single GET request is shown. This request actually never fully resolves but the video loads smoothly on my texture.

## FIREFOX:[image: firefox video loading]

The reason this is of interest to me is I am trying to map a video onto a Threejs texture and how the video loads effects when I can update my model. The fact that google only loads quite large chunks means that if the time of the video is changed the video cannot load->play in time.

One can see these results in the server I am working on:
https://blackfynnpythonlink.ml/hoverGraph/MPB/simple_heart/

Corresponding repo:
https://github.com/Tehsurfer/MPB

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly a programming question. Maybe belongs on a different SE.

Comment: I see. Thank you, you don't happen to know which one would be suitable off the top of your head do you?

Comment: Possibly [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), as it's more for general questions about software.